# Find a polynomial function g(x) that at each point has a constant orthogonal distance from f(xà

Tags: python, function, orthogonal

I'am trying to solve the following problem in python:
I have a x and y dataset. From those points, I can easily find the Lagrange poly that fits my dataset. Then I would like to find another polynomial function that has a constant orthogonal distance (d) from my function f(x).

Is there a library that could calculate it for me?

I was thinking about calculating the derivatives at each point x and calculating how much should I add to each y in order to obtain the desired new function, but I am having troubles with it.

Any ideas on how to solve it using Python?

Comment: You can define a curve with that property, but it won't (except in rare circumstances) be a polynomial. You can construct it from individual points on the original polynomial (and hence plot it if you wish), but I don't think you can write down an analytical equation for that curve. To construct it: find the derivative f' at any point; hence find the unit normal; go the required distance d along the normal and that will be the corresponding point.